# Responsive div, css and flexible in the same time?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

After you login to page: www.birkadehyasam.com with
username: korayyy
pass: abc

You will see 2 columns in the right side of the page.
If you resize your browser and make it smaller from the righthandside, one column will go below the other one.
At this point, I want the columns to extend in the browser and touch the righthandside of the browser.

How can I do this?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using width in px try to use % width.. try to give width:47% for .span5 class.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. But then will it fill all of the right handside ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using bootstrap, the `.span5` won't have a 100% width until you are at the smallest media query. You will have to modify the css for the `span5` when you reach that breakpoint OR add a class that overwrites the width of the `.span5`

Comment: add a custom `style.css` file that has `@media (width: [the breakpoint]) { .span5 { width: 100%; }` or go directly into the `bootstrap.css` file and edit it their